# How to remove Python Environment from Anaconda 3 in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I am trying to remove the Py2 environment from my Ananconda 3 installation but in vain.

I follow advice found in the official [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments)

I am asked to deactivate the environment but even after I deactivate it I get again the same message.  See below:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code and output/errors from the terminal in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, maybe it will help:

```
conda remove -n ENVIRONMENT_NAME --all
```

Here is a link to the [docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you misunderstood the documentation.  It says `conda remove --name myenv --all`.  You interpreted this as meaning you should replace `name` with the name of your environment.  But `name` is the name of the command option and can't be changed; instead you need to replace `myenv` with the name of your environment, so that the command becomes

```
conda remove --name py27 --all
```